# jQueryMobile 'data-scroll=true' does not work on dynamically injected pages

Tags: jquery, html, dom, jquery-mobile, scrollview

`data-scroll="true"` works fine if the page is static page, but if I add page dynamically using javascript it does not work.

My Header section is :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.scrollview.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.scrollview.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrollview.js"></script>
```

I also added the `data-scroll` attribute and set it to `true` using javascript, below is my code :

```
var pageHtml = "<div data-role='page' data-scroll='true' id=page" + pageId + " data-url=page" + pageId + ">";
var pageHeader = "<div data-role='header' data-position='fixed'><h1>" + menuItem + "</h1></div>";
var pageContent = "<div data-role='content' id='page" + pageId + "Content'></div>";
var page = pageHtml + pageHeader + pageContent + "</div>";
$(page).appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
```

Please help me...

Comment: Looking at what you have posted jQM does not yet support jQuery 1.7.x should be using 1.6.4, You should upgrade to jQM 1.0 also linking to a demo (like http://jsfiddle.net) would be helpful as well as any errors you are encountering

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$('yourScrollersId').scrollview();
```

I had the same problem, worked for me.

Better later than never :-)

Answer (score 1):

After a long research, what I found is-

we need to load the dynamic HTML, for each scroll block, to unique container  s.

for eg.-

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="content" id="container">

    <div id="scrollContainer"></div>

    <div id="anotherContainer"></div>

</div>
```

**JS**

if we loaded a scrollview on 'scrollContainer' at first,

```
$('#scrollContainer').html(loadHtml);
$("#scrollContainer").scrollview();
$("#scrollContainer").trigger('create');
```

then next time, we need to load in a different container-

```
$('#anotherContainer').html(loadHtml);
$("#anotherContainer").scrollview();
$("#anotherContainer").trigger('create');
```

**Optional**

To again dynamically load into `#scrollContainer`, we can remove & recreate the `<div>`.
after executing the second code block

```
$('#scrollContainer').remove();
$('#container').append('<div id="scrollContainer"></div>');
//$('#scrollContainer').empty();  // simply making this DIV empty WILL NOT WORK, we need to REMOVE DYNAMIC CLASSES, STYLES also. So, its better to recreate the LOADCONTAINER
```

other solutions should be there, but this one really works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to JQM apply that page - try

```
$(page).appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer).page();
```

or even

```
$(page).appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer).trigger('create');
```

Hope this helps

UPDATE: here's the [JQM documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html) on how to officially do this