# jQuery mobile dynamique page doesn't scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, scroll, jquery-templates

I use **jQuery mobile** Framework and **jQuery Tmpl** to create a web app for iPhone only.
Every **static** pages **work fine**.
But **dynamic** pages (*Built with Json and Tmpl*) won't scroll.

Comment: I kept only jqm CSS, but the problem still occur.

Comment: I tried .trigger( 'updatelayout' ); but still not working.

Comment: I tried .listview('refresh') doensn't help either

Comment: .scrollview() and .trigger('create') neither

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356324/jquerymobile-data-scroll-true-does-not-work-on-dynamically-injected-pages Quite same problem, no true answer there either

Comment: Tried data-scroll="true" doesn't help :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the jQuerymobile template we used, this:

```
$(document).on('touchmove', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

was preventing our page from scrolling.
Quite obvious :S

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( '#foo' ).trigger( 'updatelayout' );
```

`updatelayout` event to notify other components that they may need to adjust their layouts in response to their content changes. Developers who are building dynamic applications that inject, hide, or remove content from the page, or manipulate it in any way that affects the dimensions of the page, can also manually trigger this updatelayout event to ensure components on the page update in response to the changes.  See http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html